# Framework7 + panel-right + notifications tab + infinite scroll

Tags: infinite-scroll, html-framework-7, panels

I've got 2 panels (right and left).
Panel-right has 2 tabs, and one of it, is for displaying notifications.
How can I attach infinite scroll to this? because is not working as it does in any other page. The event handler for "infinite"

```
$$('.infinite-scroll').on('infinite', function () {
```

never gets fire as it does in the index page (which is behind the panel)

This is the html

```
<!-- Views -->
<div class="views">


  <div class="panel-overlay"></div>

    <!-- =========== PANEL IZQUIERDO ============ !-->

  <div class="panel panel-left panel-cover">
  </div>

   <div class="panel panel-right panel-cover">
    <div class="toolbar tabbar">
      <div class="toolbar-inner">
        <a href="#tab-perfil" class="tab-link active">Perfil</a>
        <a href="#tab-notificaciones" class="tab-link tab-notificaciones">Notificaciones</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs">
      <div id="tab-perfil" class="tab active">
        <div class="content-block">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-notificaciones" class="tab page-content infinite-scroll ">
        <div class="list-block">
          <ul></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- panel panel-right panel-cover !-->


  <!-- Your main view, should have "view-main" class -->
  <div class="view view-main">

    <div class="pages navbar-fixed toolbar-fixed">

      <!-- ===========  page-index ============ !-->
        <div class="page page-index" data-page="index">
```

Comment: Do you succeeded to make it work in your tab ?

Comment: Hi! not yet. Maybe in v2.0 this will be fixed.